# I had the problem to remove the white space from key values in android retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, android-json

I am trying to post the value via json to retorfit but unfortunately am getting space in json fromat so that i could not get the success reponse from retrofit in an android.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.serverurl))
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                InthreeApi apiService = retrofit.create(InthreeApi.class);
                JSONObject paramObject = null; // Main JSON Object
                JSONObject jsonFTcustomer = null;
                JSONArray jsonDetailsArray = new JSONArray();

                //String orderId=orderid.trim();
                String orderId = orderid.replaceAll("\\s", "");

                try {

                    paramObject=new JSONObject();
                    //paramObject.put("order_id",orderId.trim().replace("\\s", ""));


                    paramObject.put("order_id","orderid");


                    for(int i=0;i<productItems.size();i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
                        jsonObject.put("product_id", productItems.get(i).getProductId());
                        jsonObject.put("product_name", productItems.get(i).getProductName());
                        jsonObject.put("sku", productItems.get(i).getProductCode());
                        jsonObject.put("qty", productItems.get(i).getQty());
                        jsonDetailsArray.put(jsonObject);
                    }

                    paramObject.put("products",jsonDetailsArray);
                    Log.v("cancle_order",String.valueOf(paramObject));




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                   // jsonFTcustomer.toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");

                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), paramObject.toString());

Getting JSON:

{"order_id":" 000753398","products":[{"product_id":"16869","product_name":" Minix 4000mah Power Bank","sku":"116869","qty":"1"}]}

Expected JSON:

{"order_id":"000753398","products":[{"product_id":"16869","product_name":" Minix 4000mah Power Bank","sku":"116869","qty":"1"}]}
```

I need to remove the space order_id key value but i couldn't find the solution. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is something like below please check it.

```
for(int i=0;i<productItems.size();i++) {

      JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
      jsonObject.put("product_id", productItems.get(i).getProductId().trim());
      jsonObject.put("product_name", productItems.get(i).getProductName().trim());
      jsonObject.put("sku", productItems.get(i).getProductCode().trim());
      jsonObject.put("qty", productItems.get(i).getQty().trim());
      jsonDetailsArray.put(jsonObject);
}
```

`trim()` use this function to remove spaces.

**Update**

```
String orderId = orderid.replaceAll(" ", "");
paramObject.put("order_id",orderId);
```

Comment: paramObject.put("order_id","orderid"); am getting space here like which i have mentioned here

Comment: check my updated answer.  I think you are passing wrong value in `paramObject`.

Comment: you have to put  `orderId` in your paramObject not `"orderid"`. remove "" and replace small `i` with caps `I`.

Comment: That is not a problem becoz I just created the string to assign the value of order id string  i can use either orderid or orderID